# Start, restart or stop Varnish

Tags: nginx, centos7, varnish, php-7.1

I am using [this](https://www.tecmint.com/install-varnish-cache-for-nginx-on-centos-7/) link for installing Varnish for nginx on CentOS 7.

How can I start, restart or stop Varnish?

Answer (score 3):

> service varnish restart

Completely restarts Varnish, using the operating system mechanisms. Your cache will be flushed

> service varnish reload

Only reloads VCL. Cache is not affected.

Apart from these `service varnish start` & `service varnish stop` can be used as general commands. Using these may effect your cache directly.

Comment: If i give this comment getting error like this "Redirecting to /bin/systemctl restart  varnish.service
Failed to restart varnish.service: Unit not found.

Answer (score 1):

Use "systemctl start/restart/stop varnish".

Answer (score 0):

The post that you used for the base to install Varnish relies on installing from source. This should be avoided for many reasons:

- Security. There is no easy way to update something installed from source. Packages are meant for easy updates instead.
- Security again. You install development packages to compile. That's more software on the system, and more risk.
- Usability. It does not ship with / does not install scripts to start, restart or stop Varnish

Save yourself time, and install Varnish using official RPM repository [here](https://packagecloud.io/varnishcache/varnish5/install).

```
curl -s https://packagecloud.io/install/repositories/varnishcache/varnish5/script.rpm.sh | sudo bash
```

After this you can start, restart and stop Varnish using standard OS routines, like `service varnish restart`.

It's quick and you will be running in no time!

Comment: How to remove older varnish ?

Comment: That brings another point - you can't always delete easily something you installed from source. Try ```make uninstall``` from the source directory. This may or may not work. If it doesn't work you will have to cleanup everything manually.